# Typo3 Fluid <f:if> always returning true

Tags: typo3, fluid, fluid-layout

i want to do an "f:if condidtion={}" Command in my Fluid Template but it always returns true, always!
My Example:

```
<f:if condition="{2 == 3}">
    <f:then>
        *returned true.. do something*
    </f:then>
    <f:else>
        *returned false.. do something else*
    </f:else>
</f:if>
```

As you can cleary see, it has to be false because 2 != 3 but my f:if always returns true.
Anyone got an Idea?

Greetings
BMR

Answer (score 5):

`{...}` tries to use a variable or ViewHelper by that name. As there is none called `2 == 3`, it keeps the string `{2 == 3}` which is (after type juggling) `trueish`.

You should use `2 == 3` or rather `{myVar} == 3`.